# ¿Como tener diferentes AddOnSuccessListener?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin

Xamarin.Android C#: Tengo varios `void` que necesito tengan el `AddOnSuccessListener`, el problema es que todos se van a un mismo `OnSuccess`.

Como puedo tener 3 o mas `AddOnSuccessListener` con diferentes `OnSuccess` para cada void?

Clase:

```
public class LoginAux : Activity, IOnSuccessListener
    {
        FirebaseFirestore database;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginAux);
                
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {                
                //ShowToast("Check: Login.cs - OnCreate: " + Ex.Message);
            }

        } //Fin Void - OnCreate

public async void QuertyId()//object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {          
            try
            {                
                Query query = database.Collection("Usuarios").WhereEqualTo("Correo", "kenny@ali.com").WhereEqualTo("Contraseña", "123");
                var response = await query.Get();

                var data = (QuerySnapshot)response;
                DocID = data.Documents[0].Id;

                await database.Collection("Usuarios").Document(DocID).Get().AddOnSuccessListener(this);

                
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                
            }
        }  //Fin void QuertyId  


public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            try
            {
                var snapshot = (DocumentSnapshot)result;
                string fullname = snapshot.Get("Nombre").ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                              
            }
            
        }  //

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usa `this` porque la clase donde se llama el método `AddOnSuccessListener` implementa la interfaz `IOnSuccessListener` que contiene el método `OnSuccess`. Para tener diferentes implementaciones de `OnSuccess` se pueden crear nuevas clases que implementen la interfaz.

```
class Listener1 :  IOnSuccessListener {

   void OnSuccess(Object o){
     // código del listener 1
   }

}

class Listener2 : IOnSuccessListener{
   
    void OnSuccess(Object o){
       // código del listener 2
    }
}
```

Y para usar esos listeners creas una nueva instancia de esas clases en lugar de usar `this`:

```
await database.Collection("Usuarios").Document(DocID).Get()
    .AddOnSuccessListener(new Listener1());
```

Comment: No te comprendi

Comment: Ok, agrega el código de la clase donde llamas AddOnSuccessListener para darte otro ejemplo.

Comment: Listo, agregue la clase

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.